# How to create a "replace-second" function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

`(clojure.string/replace-first "a x x c d"  #"x" "b" )) ; Replace first`

what if I want to replace the second x in the above string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm maybe you can compromise?

```
(-> "a x x c d"  
  (clojure.string/replace-first #"x" "_")
  (clojure.string/replace-first #"x" "b" )
  (clojure.string/replace-first #"_" "x"))
```

Just make sure `_` can't be in the string.

:)

Answer (score 3):

A [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) instance lets us [iterate over the matches](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html#find-start-end-methods):

```clj
(defn replace-nth [input pattern n new-value]
  (let [m (re-matcher pattern input)]
    (loop [counter n]
      (if (.find m)
        (if (= counter 0)
          (str (subs input 0 (.start m))
               new-value
               (subs input (.end m)))
          (recur (dec counter)))
        input))))

(replace-nth "a x x c d" #"x" 1 "Mjao!")
;; => "a x Mjao! c d"
```

Comment: If `pattern` is not found, this returns `nil`. Compare `(s/replace-first "a x x c d" #"p" "Mjao!")` and `(replace-nth "a x x c d" #"p" 1 "Mjao!")`.

Comment: @MartinPůda That is a good remark! I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

For instance it could have been:

```
(let [n     #{1}
          s     "a x x x x c d"
          re    #"x"
          m     (re-find re s)
          xs    (s/split s re)
          vs    (conj (vec (take (dec (count xs)) (repeat m))) nil)
          replacement ".."]
        (apply str (interleave xs (map-indexed (fn [index v] (if (n index) replacement v)) vs))))
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, here's one more (modularized one):

first, lazy seq of ranges to replace:

```
(defn ranges [re s]
  (let [m (re-matcher re s)]
    (for [_ (range) :while (re-find m)]
      [(.start m) (.end m)])))

user> (ranges #"x" "a x x b x")
;;=> ([2 3] [4 5] [8 9])
```

then the range replace function:

```
(defn replace-range [[a b] repl s]
  (str (subs s 0 a) repl (subs s b)))

user> (replace-range [1 3] "REPLACED" "a b c d e f")

;;=> "aREPLACED c d e f"
```

and then you do whatever you need:

```
(let [s "a x x b x"]
  (map #(replace-range % "ZEE" s)
       (ranges #"x" s)))

;;=> ("a ZEE x b x" "a x ZEE b x" "a x x b ZEE")
```

or

```
(let [s "a x x b x"]
  (-> (ranges #"x" s)
      second
      (replace-range "REPLACED" s)))

;;=> "a x REPLACED b x"
```